# ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.1 and one-to-many relationship

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, symbology, relationship-class

I've been struggling to link a feature of 450 municipalities and approximately 60,000 fires that have occurred over the last 15 years. I've attempted to make a relationship class. I can see the individual events when I query a municipality but I cannot symbolize based on, perhaps, graduated symbols to represent the number of fire events normalized by size. I've attached a pic of the tables and the Identify.

Not sure if I could summarize the number of instances of fires and append them as an attribute to the municipal boundaries instead..? I'm in an FGDB, no DB backend.

[image: Tables_Identify]

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the ["Summary Statistics" tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/summary-statistics.htm) on Filtered_Fires with **Muni_Code** as your case field and COUNT of **OBJECTID** (and anything else you're interested in symbolizing on) as your statistics field(s). This will create a table that you can then join back to your municipalities.

Comment: Thanks nmpeterson, I can't use the Muni_Code to Count since it's a text field. I tried to do a "Frequency" tool and managed to get all the fires associated with their parent municipality through a Join, but no dates, which is an important feature to maintain since I'd eventually like to make this temporal.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure what you mean. Using Muni_Code as the **case field** will cause the statistics (i.e. the count of OBJECTIDs) to be calculated for each unique value of Muni_Code. Being a text field doesn't change that in any way.

Comment: I figured it out, I was erroring out on the tool using the Muni_Code. It's all good now. Thanks for the help!